# .Net Memcache with Touch and GetAndTouch Implementation

Tags: c#, .net, memcached, touch

I am currently looking into using memcache on my windows azure application, but am running into the following situation:

I have looked around for a client/server implementation of memcache for my C# for my application, and have found some really good ones! I have looked at Enyims, BeIT, memchachedotnet, and couchbase's.

However, the first three all dont have the Touch and GetAndTouch client methods, and the last one requires server installation (of which I am trying to avoid).

Are they any .net Implementations out there that do implement this? Or maybe someone has built one of their own?! :P

Thanks!

Comment: I found this file on the Enyim GitHub page, which seems to contain methods for `Touch` and `GetAndTouch`, but I'm not familiar with memchached so I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for or not: https://github.com/enyim/EnyimMemcached/blob/master/Membase/MembaseClient.cs   (do ctrl+f for `Touch`)

Comment: Ahh This was exactly what I was looking for! If I could mark your comment as an answer, I would!